Linqpad is not submitting changes
I don't know what i miss. I used it thousands of time and I updated millions of rows before.
There are two tables. One is storing definitions. One is storing relations years based. Some relations are inserted wrong years. I want to update these rows.
This is my linqpad query.
var list = ABSPaylarOlcmeProgram.Where(x => x.FKPaylarOlcme.FKPaylar.Yil != x.FKProgramCikti.Yil).ToList(); 

  foreach (var element in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element.FKProgramCiktiID);
        element.FKProgramCiktiID = BolumYeterlilik.First(x=> x.FKProgramBirimID == element.FKProgramCikti.FKProgramBirimID && x.Yil == element.FKPaylarOlcme.FKPaylar.Yil && x.Sira == element.FKProgramCikti.Sira).ID;
        Console.WriteLine(element.FKProgramCiktiID);
    }
    SubmitChanges();

ABSPaylarOlcmeProgram = relations table.
BolumYeterlilik = definitions table.
In the list I found wrong relations which are years not equals. In foreach I use element.FKProgramCiktiID for the correct definition Id. It updates when I write integer value. But It not submit changes If I query BolumYeterlilik.First
What is the problem? Anything related changes tracking?

Debug it and see if element objects are actually changed. We really can't do much here.

What does SubmitChanges do? It should be calling {DbContext}.SaveChanges()

@HansKeﬆing it SubmitChanges in LinqPad similiar method.

@HansKeﬆing Linqpad uses LINQ-to-SQL under the hood, not EF.

I solved the problem but not the way I want.
I was directly finding definition id and assign it to the value. It resets value when I call SubmitChanges(). This is still not working.
But when I directy assign foreign table record it worked.
Not working
element.FKProgramCiktiID = ....
Working
element.FKProgramCikti = ....

element.FKProgramCiktiID should work but only if  element.FKProgramCikti has not been accessed.
And in your query, it is being accessed as subquery contains element.FKProgramCikti.FKProgramBirimID
